# How to get angular project folder path in visual studio code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get angular project folder path in  visual studio code.I have opened multiple angular project in visual studio code also trying to get currently opened project folder path inside my vs code extension script.
Below the script only working to get app folder path from the currently opened project but i want to get currently opened project folder path like c:\xampp\htdocs\angularprojects\cottage

First if we can get currently opened file's project node_modules path then we can get project folder path easily.

```
var vscode = require("vscode");
var path = require("path");
function activate(context) {

var currentlyOpenTabfilePath = 
vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.fileName;

const fullPath = path.dirname(currentlyOpenTabfilePath);
const regexResp = /^(.*?)node_modules/.exec(fullPath);
const projectfolderPath = regexResp ? regexResp[1] : fullPath;
console.log(projectfolderPath); 

// Now i am getting like this projectfolderPath = c:\xampp\htdocs\angularprojects\cottage\src\app

// But actual output should be like projectfolderPath = c:\xampp\htdocs\angularprojects\cottage

}
```

Comment: split the string on '\' and remove the last 2 entries, What is `currentlyOpenTabfilePath`?

Comment: See my angular project folder sample structure:https://tutorialslink.com/Article_img/Blog_image/689d5f69-71b5-462e-8809-121fa9fd96bc.png

Comment: If i open any file from the project i want to get project folder path link like c:\xampp\htdocs\angularprojects\cottage

Comment: `vscode.workspace.rootPath`